# Images not lining up correctly

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create a list of images (which act as links) that will light up when hovered over. However, adding a `<div class="hover">` to the beginning of every image stopped them displaying in a horizontal row. How do I fix it so that it allows me to have it in a horizontal row?

```css
.hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}

.hover:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#000000">

<ul class="list-inline">
          <div class="hover">
             <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/youtube-active.png" height="39px" width="99px"></div></li>
          <div class="hover">
              <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/twitter-active.png" height="56px" width="56px"></div></li>
          <div class="hover">
              <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/facebook-active.png" height="56px" width="56px"></div></li>
          <div class="hover">
              <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/soundcloud-active.png" height="56px" width="72"></div></li>
          <div class="hover">
             <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/googleplus-active.png" height="56px" width="56px"></div></li>
          <div class="hover">
              <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/steam-active.png" height="56px" width="56px"></div></li>
          <div class="hover">
              <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/twitch-active.png" height="56px" width="56px">
            </div></li>
```

Sorry for any poor code or a confusing question, this is my first post.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divs are block level elements by default and take up as much width as possible, so change the display from block to inline by adding `display: inline;` to your hover class:

```css
.hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  display: inline;
}
.hover:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#000000">

  <ul class="list-inline">
    <div class="hover">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/youtube-active.png" height="39px" width="99px">
    </div>
    </li>
    <div class="hover">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/twitter-active.png" height="56px" width="56px">
    </div>
    </li>
    <div class="hover">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/facebook-active.png" height="56px" width="56px">
    </div>
    </li>
    <div class="hover">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/soundcloud-active.png" height="56px" width="72">
    </div>
    </li>
    <div class="hover">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/googleplus-active.png" height="56px" width="56px">
    </div>
    </li>
    <div class="hover">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/steam-active.png" height="56px" width="56px">
    </div>
    </li>
    <div class="hover">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/twitch-active.png" height="56px" width="56px">
    </div>
    </li>
```

Another option would be to float the `.hover` divs left by using `float:left`:

```css
.hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  float:left;
}
.hover:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#000000">

  <ul class="list-inline">
    <div class="hover">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/youtube-active.png" height="39px" width="99px">
    </div>
    </li>
    <div class="hover">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/twitter-active.png" height="56px" width="56px">
    </div>
    </li>
    <div class="hover">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/facebook-active.png" height="56px" width="56px">
    </div>
    </li>
    <div class="hover">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/soundcloud-active.png" height="56px" width="72">
    </div>
    </li>
    <div class="hover">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/googleplus-active.png" height="56px" width="56px">
    </div>
    </li>
    <div class="hover">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/steam-active.png" height="56px" width="56px">
    </div>
    </li>
    <div class="hover">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/twitch-active.png" height="56px" width="56px">
    </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a div for each image and divs are block level elements which takes a complete row, however you can make a block level element to act like an inline element by setting its display property to inline. e.g. `display: inline;`

```css
.list-inline{
   text-align: center; 
}

.hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    display: inline;
}

.hover:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#000000">

<ul class="list-inline">
          <div class="hover">
             <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/youtube-active.png" height="39px" width="99px"></div></li>
          <div class="hover">
              <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/twitter-active.png" height="56px" width="56px"></div></li>
          <div class="hover">
              <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/facebook-active.png" height="56px" width="56px"></div></li>
          <div class="hover">
              <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/soundcloud-active.png" height="56px" width="72"></div></li>
          <div class="hover">
             <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/googleplus-active.png" height="56px" width="56px"></div></li>
          <div class="hover">
              <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/steam-active.png" height="56px" width="56px"></div></li>
          <div class="hover">
              <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ItsGeekyPixel/Website/master/Images/PNGs/twitch-active.png" height="56px" width="56px">
            </div></li>
```